# Por que (a < x < b) produz um resultado diferente de ((a < x) and (x < b))?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados

Listar todos os campos de todos os produtos cujo custo acrescido de 30% seja maior do que 8 e menor que 10.

Essa foi a minha resposta:

```
SELECT * FROM `produtos` WHERE (8 < (pcusto*1.3) < 10);
```

Esse é o gabarito:

```
SELECT * FROM `produtos` WHERE 8 < (pcusto*1.3) AND (pcusto*1.3) < 10;
```

Embora o raciocínio matemático esteja correto, o PhpMyAdmin identifica resultado muito diferentes. No primeiro caso ele retorna mais de 1000 registros, já na resposta do gabarito ele retorna apenas 60.

Qual é a diferença primordial que tem entre cada linha de código?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Acontece que o SQL executará algo diferente do que você imagina com a sintaxe que utilizou:

```
WHERE a < x < b
```

Esta expressão poderia ser escrita como `(a < x) < b` produzindo o mesmo resultado, porém deixando um pouco mais explícito o que acontece. Primeiro será avaliado a primeira parte da comparação, `a < x`, e o resultado desta expressão será comparado com o último valor.

Se `x` for maior que `a`, a comparação `a < x` retornará verdadeiro, `true`, que será avaliado como o inteiro 1, assim comparando se `1 < b`. No seu caso, `b` vale 10, então `1 < b` é verdadeiro, retornando assim todos os registros que possuem `pcusto * 1.3` maior que 8.

Se `x` for menor que `a`, a comparação `a < x` retornará falso, `false`, que será avaliado como o inteiro 0, assim comparando se `0 < b`. No seu caso, `b` vale 10, então `1 < b` é verdadeiro, retornando assim todos os registros que possuem `pcusto * 1.3` menor que 8.

Ou seja, basicamente a sua comparação `8 < pcusto*1.3 < 10` sempre será verdadeira, sendo retornado na consulta todos os registros da tabela.

Quando você separa em duas comparações independentes, você avaliará logicamente o resultado de ambas, obtendo o resultado esperado.